# In Excel determine # in cell

Tags: excel, search, text

In a simple Excel if statement how do you determine if a cell is the American pound "#" or hashtag value.  Simple I know but not for me at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula `=IF(D1="#",TRUE,FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

Simply use

```
=A1="#"
```

The result will be either TRUE or FALSE.